# How to implement hybrid recyclerview with multiple adapter and show item in order?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I want to achieve exactly same as show in picture.

[image]

I have multiple adapters for multiple recyclerview. I want to combine them in single fragment. I want to achieve the result from each adapter item show sequetially butt not recyclerview in sequence.

I don't have viewtype stored in database, so can't use multiple view holder concept. Also I'm fetching data from multiple sources.

Can anybody guide me how to achieve this behaviour?

Note: I'm at initial stage to achieve this.

Comment: You no need multiple adapters... Multi view holder enough for the logic .   Follow this sample https://blog.mindorks.com/recyclerview-multiple-view-types-in-android. And construct your list

Comment: @GobuCSG I don't have viewtype stored in database, so can't use multiple view holder concept. Also I'm fetching data from multiple sources.

Comment: That's okay... Every item have some unique right... You can manage with that... Write a global data class...  Like BaseResponse inside put model1 2 3 4 something like that... Then if 1 not null render 1 viewholder like that you can implement